# How can I automatically load an sqlite extension in sqlite3 for node.js?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm using the [SQLite3 bindings for Node.js](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3).

I my app I require an [sqlite extension](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html).  I'm able to load and use it in my app just fine.

The [sqlite3 API](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#loadextensionpath--callback) has a call to load extensions, but I want the extension(s) loaded without having to make the call.

The issue is that, without the extension, sqlite tools e.g. database browsers can't properly access the database and so far, I haven't found any that allow the user to specify extensions to be loaded.

I've searched for every kind of import/require etc. hook that I can think of but I can't find a place to insert code to be run as part of the initial sqlite3 require() that would allow me to automatically load the extensions needed to access my database, regardless of what app loads sqlite3.

I thought I might be able to just compile the extensions in, but I didn't find anything in the  [the compile docs](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) about extensions other than a couple that are supported out of the box.  Nor were there any I could find in the  [sqlite3 source install docs](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3#source-install).

Is there a way to get sqlite3 extensions automatically loaded by sqlite3, regardless of what app is loading it?

Comment: I'm using SQLite with the node.js bindings as well and just discovered an extension I want to use so started looking for similar information.  The node wrapper exposes the `loadExtension` function with the following signature:
`loadExtension(filename: string, callback?: (err: Error | null) => void): this;`
Can you call this when your app starts?  Is this what you are looking for?  I haven't tried it yet myself but thought I would ask.

Comment: @WolfieWolf I have no problem loading the extensions myself, it's 3d party apps like database browsers that have trouble with my database because they don't have the extension loaded.  I want the extension to be integrated such that *any* app that loads sqlite3 automatically also loads the extension.

Comment: Ah I see, I experienced the same problem when connecting IntelliJ to the database as well.  I haven't attempted to find a solution yet but if I find one, I'll let you know.  Thanks for the clarification.